# Protected member access compiles differently in g++ and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, g++

I have the following code with two levels of inheritance of class templates:

```
template <typename FIELD>
class Class1
{
protected:
    int n;
    FIELD data1;
public:
    Class1();
    virtual ~Class1() {}
};

template <typename FIELD> class Class3;

template <typename FIELD>
class Class2 : public Class1<FIELD>
{
protected:
    using Class1<FIELD>::n;
    FIELD data2;
public:
    Class2();
    virtual ~Class2() {}
    int Method(Class3<FIELD> &) const;
};

template <typename FIELD>
class Class3 : public Class2<FIELD>
{
protected:
    using Class1<FIELD>::n;
    FIELD data3;
public:
    Class3();
    virtual ~Class3() {}
};

template <typename FIELD>
int Class2<FIELD> :: Method(Class3<FIELD> & U) const
{
    U = Class3<FIELD>();
    int g = U.n;
    return g;
}

template class Class2<double>;
```

I compile this into an object file in Ubuntu using command:
`g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Wfatal-errors -o Test.o Test.cpp`
and no error whatsoever is generated, the object file is created just fine!

However, when I try to compile the very same code from within Visual Studio using **Ctrl+F7**, I get C2248 error that reads:
'Class3::n': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Class3'

Is there a bug in one of the compilers? Which one follows standard? Despite my faith in g++, I'm inclined to think that VS is more correct in this case since variable `n` should be accessed by `Class2` only from `Class1` (since it is base class for `Class2`) but not from `Class3`.

Note that I need to add line `friend int Class2::Method(Class3<FIELD> &) const;`
within `Class3` declaration to bypass C2248 error in VS.

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: This is a GCC bug fixed since GCC 6.

Comment: @Oliv Thanks. Could you please give a specific link to where this bug or its fix is reported?

Comment: I prefer to offer you the pleasure to find it!! [gcc bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). I have just checked the behavior on compiler explorer.